# Can't install Semantic-UI via NPM

Tags: npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I've been trying to install Semantic via NPM for a while now and am having problems. I run `npm install semantic-ui` and it goes through the setup process. However, it stops at `Finished 'install' after 3.61 s` and never exits the process. If I manually cancel the process and navigate to the semantic folder and run `gulp build` I'm told there's no local gulp found. So I run `npm install gulp` just for fun. It installs and I run `gulp build` again but all of the gulp dependencies are missing.

Any ideas? It's getting frustrating because I've been tinkering with it for a few hours instead of getting to work on the actual project. Running `npm install` in the semantic directory or my project directory doesn't work either. Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** I tried creating a new Ubuntu VM and installing Semantic the same way I was on my Mac. It worked with no problems leading me to believe it's something to do with my configuration on my Mac.

Comment: P.S. I tried in a different directory and got the same result... Really not sure what could be causing the issues.

Comment: What errors are you getting when you say `It installs and I run gulp build again but all of the gulp dependencies are missing.`?

Comment: @Filype currently I'm getting `No gulpfile found.` I feel like the install isn't actually completing because all that's in my semantic folder is src and tasks.

Comment: I just installed this npm packaged. It looks like after the message you received `Finished 'install' after 3.61 s` you need to wait to as some npm packages install is ran?

Comment: inside the folder semantic there's a gulpfile

Comment: @Filype well, there's no indication that anything is happening after I get `Finished install`. Nothing happens if I wait. On my Ubuntu VM, I got a spinning cursor and a bunch of npm packages installed like you said. Nothing on my Mac. And there's no gulpfile in my semantic folder.

Answer (score 3):

This is really odd, but after I got to the `Finished 'install'` step, nothing was happening. Just a solid cursor when the node deps should've been installing. I decided to hit return just to see if anything would happen and that seems to have done it. Hitting return gives me the spinning cursor and the deps install. I can successfully run `gulp build` after that. Weird.

Comment: Huhhhh, you saved my day.

Comment: `I decided to hit return just to see if anything would happen and that seems to have done it.`
same happened to me but unfortunately I cannot do gulp **build**
I get:
`Cannot find semantic.json. Run "gulp install" to set-up Semantic`
I have tried moving the semantic.json from project root to where semantic gulp is with no luck

Comment: Just a heads-up, it appears the issue has been fixed in the latest version of Semantic.